# Python scripts in different directories use the same file in which import breaks

Tags: python, file, flask, import, directory

So I have a tree file like that:

```
scriptA.py
folder/
------scriptB.py
------some_function.py
------utils.py
```

File `some_function.py` imports something from file `utils.py` and both scripts (`scriptA.py` and `scriptB.py`) use function from `some_function.py` file. The problem is import in `some_function.py`. It imports something from `utils.py` and when I run `scriptA.py` it must be `from folder.utils import smth` but when I run `scriptB.py` it must be `from utils import smth`. How to make that import to work in both cases?

Edit: 
`scriptA.py` runs flask app 
`scriptB.py` runs some normal python script

Comment: can you try using relative import in your some_functions.py use `from .utils import smth`

Comment: then I am getting `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package` on that relative import

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can make it work:

```
├── a.py
└── folder
    ├── b.py
    ├── somefunction.py
    └── utils.py
```

utils.py

```py
dummy = 123
```

somefunction.py

```py
from .utils import dummy
```

b.py

```py
from .somefunction import dummy
print(dummy)
```

a.py

```py
from folder.somefunction import dummy
print(dummy)
```

then you can execute a and b at the same location by:

```
jamess-mbp-2:demo jlin$ python a.py 
123
jamess-mbp-2:demo jlin$ python -m folder.b
123
```

Comment: Thank you it works perfectly. The thing I was missing was running `b.py` in wrong way. Could you please explain why did you use flag `-m` and `folder.b` notation?

Comment: `b.py` is a module inside `folder` package, the `-m` is to "run module as script".